# A font like RomanS in appearance but with support for more characters (Autocad)?

Tags: autocad, truetype-fonts

In a Autocad 2010 installation, the standard font used is [RomanS](http://www.azfonts.net/load_font/romans.html).

That font is so limited on characters, so when I use "text" command I cannot add "³" on text of cubic meters measures (a "?" is displayed instead of the "³" character - see isolated text on figure below and [Font characters > Latin Supplement range](http://www.azfonts.net/load_font/romans.html)).

When I use a dimension command, like multileader, Autocad "corrects" that issue using another font that support that missing character, resulting on an awful mixture (see text on multileader below - on multileader text properties, we can see `3m{\fArial|b0|i0|c0|p34;³}`).

[image: autocad snapshot]

I can easily change that font with another, like Verdana, Times New Roman... that have more characters than RomanS font, but I would like to use an alternative font more like RomanS in appearance.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for a font of your preference at the [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/).

It contains hundreds of free, open-source fonts, available in TTF format.

**After some searching, I've found this one:**

[Open Sans Condensed](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed) by [Steve Matteson](https://profiles.google.com/107777320916704234605/about), that is very close to the "RomanS Regular" and supports the required chars.

Comment: Wait a minute, Google Web Fonts isn't more for... web fonts? If you just want fonts, you can try [dafont](http://dafont.com/).

Comment: More, but not limited to... :)

Comment: But it's certainly more limited, since many fonts aren't distributed as web fonts :P

Comment: Hey, its just a suggestion, I've even searched for a font close to the "RomanS Regular"! :) *(just trying to provide some help)*

Comment: @Zuul, the RomanS Autocad uses is already RomanS Regular (see my link)

Comment: we can download it on http://www.fontex.org/download/Open-sans.ttf. it is more like arial, not the mentioned, but thanks for help

Comment: @Zuul Ah, of course, I also just wanted to chip in my 2 cents :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [Ubuntu font](http://font.ubuntu.com/)? It's stupidly legible and has all the characters you need.

It also has several weights (Light, Regular, Medium and Bold), plus italic versions of all them, also a Condensed variant and even a Monospace one. Maybe you'd like the light one:

[image: Ubuntu Light]